# ¿Por qué se usa doble asterisco (**) en parámetros de funciones en C++ y que utilidad tiene?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

estoy aprendiendo a implementar listas enlazadas en C++ y tengo un código para insertar elementos a la lista desde la izquierda. No entiendo la función del doble asterisco de parametro que usa la función de agregar elementos, ni por que se usa. Si alguien pudiera aclarármelo, se lo agradecería.

```
struct nodeList{
    int dato;
    nodeList *next;
};
typedef struct nodeList nodo;

void agregarIzq(nodo **l, int n);

int main(){
nodo *lista = NULL;

for(int i = 50; i >= 10 ; i-=10){
    agregarIzq(&lista, i);
}

void agregarIzq(nodo **l, int n){ 
    nodo *nuevo = new nodo();
    nuevo->dato = n;
    nuevo->next = *l;
    *l = nuevo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En C++ hay diferentes tipos de dato, entres ellos int, float, double bool, char, variantes de esos y los creados por el usuario. Pero hay un tipo especial es que es el apuntador (pointer). Estos están concebidos para que almacenen direcciones de memoria en las que está ubicado algún valor.

Para declarar una variable, escribes el tipo de dato y el nombre de la variable. Dada una variable y conocida su dirección de memoria, esta puedes almacenarla en otra variable de tipo apuntador. para declararla, utilizas el mismo tipo de dato de la variable original junto al operador *. Ese operador indica que la variable es de tipo apuntador.

Ejemplos:

```
int * p1; // Apuntador a entero 
bool * p2; // Apuntador a bool 
char * p3; // Apuntador a carácter
```

Las tres variables anteriores son capaces de almacenar direcciones memoria donde haya un entero, un bool y un carácter respectivamente. Como estas son variables, también estarán almacenadas en otra posición de memoria, y yo podría querer almacenar la dirección de memoria de una variable que almacene otra dirección de memoria utilizando dos veces el *, que significaría que es un apuntador a apuntador de otro tipo de dato. Por ejemplo:

```
int ** p;
```

Es capaz de almacenar la dirección de memoria de un apuntador a entero. Igual puedes seguir añadiendo todos los * que sean necesarios para crear una secuencia de apuntadores.

Ahora bien C++, esta es la declaración típica de un arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
int a[10];
```

Genera un arreglo para 10 enteros. Implícitamente el nombre a almacena la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo, por lo tanto, puedes tener la declaración que sigue:

```
int * p = a;
```

Por lo tanto, un arreglo puede ser declarado como un apuntador. Para implementar una matriz, puedes crear un arreglo de arreglos (esto es entrar ya en memoria dinámica

).

Entonces la variable que declaras, es un apuntador a arreglos, estos otros arreglos son apuntadores también, por esa razón, un arreglo de dos dimensiones, puedes declararlo de la siguiente forma:

```
int ** m;
```

C++ tiene el operador new para apartar memoria dinámicamente, al invocar el operador, este retorna la dirección de memoria que se le asigna, por ejemplo:

```
int * i = new int;
```

Aparta una nueva dirección de memoria para almacenar enteros y esa dirección es almacenada en i. Para arreglos usamos el operador []. Por ejemplo:

```
int * a = new int[10];
```

Y con eso apartamos memoria para almacenar 10 enteros y la dirección del primer elemento queda almacenada en a. Si quisieramos un arreglo de 10 arreglos de 5 enteros por ejemplo haríamos esto:

```
int ** m = new int*[10]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
  m[i] = new int[5];
```

Dado que m almacena la dirección de memoria del primer elemento, y como m almacena otros arreglos, entonces ese primer elemento es un apuntador también, por eso de declara como un apuntador a apuntador de enteros.

referencia [Alejandro Mujica, Professor en Universidad de Los Andes - Venezuela (2015)](https://es.quora.com/profile/Alejandro-Mujica)

Comment: Como aporte a la respuesta, los punteros a punteros (\*\*) como una forma de cambiar la dirección de un puntero (\*), son un regalo de C, cuando las referencias no existían. Estando en C++ considera pasar una variable por referencia. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c19a720cb9a1d2e